# How to render backend data in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, rendering

I have backend data displaying but I'm trying to render the data using expansion panel but not sure how to do so I would be really appreciated If I can get any recommendation or help.

TS

```
  constructor(private HelpService: HelpService) {}
  helpSection: {[key: string]: HelpSection } = {};

  helpSection$ = this.HelpService.getHelpSection();


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.HelpService.getHelpSection().subscribe(() => {
    } )

  }
```

HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel-header style="align-items: center;">
    <div *ngFor= "let help of helpSection$ | async">{{help.sectionName}}</div>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <a mat-list-item (click)="clicked(1)">Here it will display subSections</a>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over parent `<mat-expansion-panel>`

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="exp-panel" *ngFor= "let help of helpSection$ | async">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header style="align-items: center;">
     <div >{{help.sectionName}}</div>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <a mat-list-item (click)="clicked(1)">Here it will display subSections</a>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**Styling**

```
.exp-panel {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi...thank you so much for this but just wondering how I can make space between each sections/ expansion panel?.

Comment: @aasemovie which space you are talking about?

Comment: Hi..I uploaded the image. can you please check it out again on my post. thanks

Comment: @aasemovie you can add style I have updated my answer added `exp-panel` class with basic styling you can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor need to be in "mat-expansion-panel" tag

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let help of helpSection$ | async">
```